# Getting Numberformatexception when using BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, numberformatexception

I am trying to solve Project Euler problem 15 using method (m+n)!/(m)! * (n)! wherein m & n are grid's length & breadth.

I have converted all values of factorials into BigInteger, still, show error on run..Help !

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;


public class Problem15 {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int length = getLength();
        int width = length;

        BigInteger Lfact = new BigInteger("fact(length)");
        BigInteger Wfact = new BigInteger("fact(width)");
        BigInteger LWfact = new BigInteger("fact(Length+width)");

        BigInteger Denom = Lfact.multiply(Wfact);

        System.out.println("For grid size "+length+"X"+width+" the total no of routes are "+LWfact.divide(Denom));

    }

    private static int getLength() {
        System.out.print("Please enter grid length - ");
        Scanner inp1 = new Scanner (System.in);

        int length = inp1.nextInt();

        inp1.close();

        return length;  
    }

    public  BigInteger fact(int num) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");

        for(int i = num; i > 1; i--) {
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new BigInteger("fact(length)")` - where did you read that this is valid?

Comment: my error list are Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fac"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Problem15.main(Problem15.java:15)

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Javadoc of BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-):

> public BigInteger(String val)
>
> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger. The String representation consists of an optional minus
>   sign followed by a sequence of one or more decimal digits. The
>   character-to-digit mapping is provided by Character.digit. The String
>   may not contain any extraneous characters (whitespace, for example).

So clearly, your use of the constructor is illegal as the error message tells us:

> NumberFormatException  ....  BigInteger.(Unknown Source) at
>   Problem15.main(Problem15.java:15)